# what is wrapper function and how to use it?

Tags: java, recursion, wrapper

For my homework, I am required to use a function called wrapper function to validate the parameter for a recursive function, which I don't understand what it means. All i understand from wrapper function is it does nothing but just wraps around a function eg:

```
private static int recursive(int n){
    //do something
    .
    .
    .
}

public static int recursiveWrap(int n){
    return recursive(n);
}
```

I dont even know if the code above is the correct implementation for wrapper, but I know that it does nothing for the recursive function but just redundancy.

How am I supposed to use the wrapper function to validate the parameter? my recursive function has a base case which it will reach without the help of wrapper.

Comment: "Validating the parameter" literally means that check if the parameter is valid for the recursive function, so the actual recursive function can skip such step

Comment: they give you homework without explaining what it is?

Comment: @MT756 in my homework, i was asked to do exception handling, which makes me thing that i have to validate the input, then i was asked to do wrapper function as well, which i dont understand.

Comment: @TheGoldy yeah, all the lecture slide has is half a page of powerpoint slide on wrapper.

Comment: Then do the exception handling in the wrapper function (a one time check), so you don't need to do so in the recursive function (a check which occurs every recursive call).

Comment: @MT756 i see, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a wrapper function would serve a purpose (otherwise there would be no reason for it to exist).

One such purpose could be to first validate the input before calling the actual recursive function (as is the case in your example), e.g. like this:

```
public static int recursive(int n){
   //do something
   .
   .
   .
}

public static int recursiveWrap(int n){
   if( n < 0 ) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("only positive arguments are allowed");
   }
   return recursive(n); 
}
```

Another purpose could be to provide a convenient entry point for recursion, e.g. for quicksort (I'll just use `int[]` for simplicity reasons, a real world example would more likely use generic arrays or lists):

```
private static void recursiveQS(int[] array, int left, int right) {
  //actual implementation here
}

//that's what the user would call
public static void quickSort(int[] array) {
   recursiveQS(array, 0, array.length);
}
```

Why would you want to use wrapper functions? There are multiple possible reasons:

- Keep the recursive function as simple as possible.
- Validation checks often need to be done once so doing it in the recursive function would execute unnecessary code (and thus result in lower performance).
- Provide a simple entry point for callers and handle any parameter mapping, setup etc. in the wrapper.
- For more general purpose recursive functions there might be special validation or setup that only applies to certain situations and types of parameters. In those cases you might want to provide special wrapper functions for the special cases, i.e. you again keep the recursive function as simple as possible.

Comment: i see, so does having a wrapper function improve the performance in anyway?

Comment: @JamesWong in many cases that would improve performance although you'd probably not notice it in many cases or it wouldn't matter that much. The performance improvement would result from less code being executed (especially if validation would be complex) but there's also some cost involved in calling another function (which in most cased can be neglected though).

Answer (score 3):

You are in the right direction.

Before calling the existing recursive method, you need to validate the parameter and take *some* action if the parameter is invalid

You haven't given the details on what to validate.

*Example:* If the parameter `n` should be within 1 to 10, you can add an *if* check to do that validation

```
public static int recursiveWrap(int n) {
    if (n < 0 || n > 10) {
       //some action
    }
    return recursive(n);
}
```

*some action* - can be anything like throwing an exception or returning a default result (maybe after logging a warning message).

In Java, usually a `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown to denote the argument passed is invalid.

```
if (n < 0 || n > 10) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The parameter value must be between 1 and 10 (inclusive)");
}
```

Comment: i see, thank you for the answer. Out of curiosity, does wrapper function improve the performance of the recursive function?? or it just provide a place for validation? and when will it be a good idea to use wrapper function? because I can just add the validation inside the recursion function itself and it still works as expected.

Comment: @James the wrapper function means the argument is only validated once rather than every recursive call.

Comment: Also, you can create different such wrapper functions that can do different things while having the core logic separately

Answer (score 0):

From my quick research on the subject, it seems the goal is to have a function validate the integer before calling the recursive function to avoid errors. For example, if I was writing a recursive function for calculating the factorial of an integer, I would want to make sure the integer is positive or zero before calling my method.

```
public int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
    {
         return 1;
    }
    return n * factorial(n-1);
}

public int factorialWrapper(int n)
{
    if(n < 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return factorial(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A wrapper for a recursive function is nothing more than a function which has
the responsibility of calling a recursive function.
Why it is used:
1)For providing a user user-friendly way of using the recursive function (since the parameters of a recursive function can be sometimes cryptic for the user and they have default values which make the function work for the most time)
2)For validation.

The following example will display all possible combinations of `{0, 1, 2, 3}`
in a length of 4. The function `backtracking()` is a wrapper for `back(int)`

I have written the following code in C++, if you want to translate it into java just
replace the two functions with static functions in your Java main class, replace `cout` with `System.out.println();`, remove the `#include` directive and `using namespace std;
and it will work;

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int a[4];

void back(int i)
{
  if(i == 4)
  {
    for(int j = 0;j < 4;j++)
    cout << a[j] << ' ';

    cout << endl;
  }
  for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
  {
    a[i] = j;
    back(i+1);
  }
}

void backtracking() {
  back(0);
}

int main() {
   backtracking();
   return 0;
}
```